# Extracting depth images using rosrun command using realsense camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, realsense-camera, depth-image, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I entered this command to extract depth images from intel realsense R200 camera:

```
rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

I wasn't able to get the images, instead showed this error:

```
[ERROR] [1529053683.952956798]: Unable to convert 16UC1 image to bgr8
[ WARN] [1529053683.953020485]: Couldn't save image, no data!
```

When i entered this command for color images, it worked:

```
rosrun image_view extract_images _sec_per_frame:=0.01 image:=/camera/color/image_raw
```

How can this issue be resolved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294198/extracting-depth-images-using-rosrun-command-using-realsense-camera/) by [janhvi_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/35708/janhvi_02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PratNag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28957/pratnag/) on 2018-06-19**:
Can you list all the published image topics? You cannot extract from image:=/camera/depth/image_raw because the format needed for extract_images is different. Maybe there is different topic like depth_registered or depth_rect...I have used the zed camera and had faced similar problems.

**Comment by [janhvi_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/35708/janhvi_02/) on 2018-06-21**:
I tried for dpeth_registered and depth_rectify but I think i need to provide encoding for depth images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*extract_images* can only save images with bgr8 encoding. You could try using [image_saver](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.image_saver) which provide option for setting encoding of the image topic, something like so:

```
rosrun image_view image_saver _encoding:=16UC1 image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [mathsci](https://answers.ros.org/users/35967/mathsci/) with karma: 41 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janhvi_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/35708/janhvi_02/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thanks a lot, i could extract depth images using this command.

**Comment by [janhvi_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/35708/janhvi_02/) on 2018-06-29**:
Can you also provide a single command for extracting both depth and color images?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-29**:
@janhvi_02 if this answered your question then please click on the check mark to mark it as correct.